# Duct to vent connection too close and awkward

Tags: hvac, ducts

I recently finished adding an office to the house.  There is ductwork running along the unfinished wall of the new room, and I picked out a good place on the wall to add the vent.

What I didn't realize is that it was placed very close to the pre-cut "take-off" in the ductwork itself. I ended up having to wrap the flex duct around in a very awkward and silly way in order to approach both ends at the correct angle.

Surely there's a better way to do this.  Is there some kind of "boxy" piece of duct that would work better here?  Or does this just happen sometimes?

[image: goofyflexduct]

(Don't mind the insulation, it's only halfway on there but I'm sure it needs to be insulated with all of that surface area.)

Comment: Would be amaze at what a decent tinsmith can do.  Do not know if you can just pick up the right piece at a big box store, but most furnace/HVAC shops should have a person that can make a piece for you that looks nicer.

Comment: Hard to tell without trying - quite possibly a normal adjustable elbow can be adjusted to work but can't really say for sure without removing that and standing there trying it and rotating bits and trying again (they can go all the way from "straight" to 90 degrees, but hard to see if the length will work out, etc.) crip659's method will work, if you get the tinsmith accurate measurements.

Comment: Isn't your pretzel :) just a standard semi-rigid section of ducting that you can cut to the desired length with tin snips? I'd use worm-gear hose clamps to fasten the ends securely, and a quality aluminum HVAC sealing tape in place of what looks to be old-school cloth duct tape.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you take two of the adjustable vent pipes you could connect them together to also improve the air flow.

By turning them around the axis you can get any curvature you need.

[image: adjustable]

Comment: this wont work. it will be impossible to line them up correctly

Comment: There are flatter fittings used to squeeze a drier against a wall. Check your local hardware or home renovation outlets, or search on line.